# Android type with "..."

Tags: java, types

I'm a new android developper and I'm trying to undersand a working code because I need to do something similar and I can't figure out what the "..." means after the type. Example :

```
onProgressUpdate(String... values){
//todo
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a variadic function, it can take any number of String arguments:

```
onProgressUpdate("Str1", "string 2", "Another string");
```

In the function the `values` will have a type of `String[]`:

```
System.out.println(values[0]); // This is "Str1"
```

The types of the arguments are still checked, so this is a compile-time error:

```
onProgressUpdate(1, "String", true); // Error: Must all be strings.
```

Answer (score 1):

String... means serval Strings.And in the method, you can get the Strings by values[n].

```
onProgressUpdate(String... values){
//todo
}
```

You can call it by onProgressUpdate(string1).

And use values[0] for string1 in the method.

Or onProgressUpdate(string1,string2,string3).

And use values[0] for string1,
 values[1] for string2,
 values[2] for string3 in the method.